# How can you keep Bootstrap's striped table rows styles working when using ember.js

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, ember.js, twitter-bootstrap-3

Ember injects script tags into the dom which prevents the bootstrap CSS from working.

The dom may look something like:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
  <script id="metamorph ...
  <tr ...
  <script id="metamorph ...
  <script id="metamorph ...
  <tr ...
  <script id="metamorph ...
  <tr ...
```

The bootstrap CSS selects which cells to highlight using nth-child(odd) selectors which means the table does not have the correctly striped background color.

Can I override the CSS with the correct style for this case?

Answer (score 1):

You can override the twitter CSS with this:

```
/* Override and remove the bootstrap style, as ember breaks it */
.table-striped>tbody>tr:nth-child(odd)>td, .table-striped>tbody>tr:nth-child(odd)>th {
    background-color: inherit;
}

/* Instead, use nth-of-type selector to effectively ignore the script tags */
.table-striped>tbody>tr:nth-of-type(odd)>td, .table-striped>tbody>tr:nth-of-type(odd)>th {
    background-color: #F9F9F9;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

or use :nth-child-of-type

sometime soon, ember will no longer need to use script tags. For more information checkout https://github.com/tildeio/htmlbars lots of work left, but it will help with this problem, and many more.

Comment: You mean, "nth-of-type", as was my solution ;) htmlbars looks promising though